# Merging lines (that might cross) at common endpoints without multi-part features in the result

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, arcgis-10.3, dissolve

I have a polyline dataset I'm trying to merge / dissolve segments based on an attribute into continuous single lines. The problem is that some of those segments cross each other but need to be represented as a single-part feature in the end result. The segments share, at most, one endpoint with another segment of the same value and should all snap together nicely since they were digitized that way. (The data will eventually be used in a geometric network and we don't want net junctions diverting traces.)

Has anyone managed to automate this process with my criteria? I've tried various combinations of the Dissolve, Unsplit Line and Merge tools in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3, all to failing to create the continuous lines. Non-ArcGIS based solutions are welcome if that will get the job done.

**Update**:

So the end goal is to connect separated features and produce continuous feature that loops over itself without the inclusion of the a vertex where the lines cross.

Features before dissolve
[image: Features before dissolve]
Post dissolve - No multipart, Unsplit (per Michael's suggestion). Three features are created as a result (The selected feature, plus features just north and west from the denoted intersection.)
[image: Dissolve - No multipart, Unsplit (per Michael's suggestion)]

Comment: Do the same attribute segments have common sink? Would you like a single line from very top to sink? Any actual diversions, i.e. 2 segments running out from single node?

Comment: Dissolve http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000 - no multipart, unsplit lines. That will sort the geometries out but as for the fields/values what's up with them? are individual attributes required?... if you have an advanced license you can find them using Feature Vertices to Points (both ends, Dangle) connected endpoints are select all BOTH_ENDS then unselect near DANGLE. That will find the likely places lines will dissolve.

Comment: I'm not really following the cross but can't be multipart thing. Are you saying the tools are introducing new vertices where they shouldn't? Can you provide a screenshot of a problem area?

Comment: Hey @ChrisW, the key here is the intention to use this data in a network, in a network lines that cross aren't connected (think pipeline/powerline) so a network trace will not go awry. Only lines that are truly connected should be traceable... the merge/dissolve is not really necessary except to simplify the data before building the network, perhaps each section (like power pole to power pole) is a 2 part line and a bit of simplification will speed up the network. This sort of data cleansing is important while it's still just lines as editing in a network is a *pain*.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I got that part; what I'm getting at is the planarize lines issue. If two lines cross and the allow multipart option isn't checked with dissolve, they should not become a single entity and no vertex should be introduced where they cross even if they have the same dissolve attribute. OP says merge/dissolve isn't working and that singlepart/multipart is an issue. I just think a graphic example of what the problem is would make it a lot clearer. Your first comment may be the answer, but the question isn't clear on exactly what is being done (and possibly done wrong).

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson is correct. The goal is to simplify the network features. The value I refer to is just a means of denoting the whole segment. All other attributes can be always be rejoined. I'll update with some screenshots.

Comment: @FelixIP Sinks/sources won't play a role in this network. We do have point features that will participate in the network and serve as diversions but not places like these since this is in real life a single continuous feature.

Comment: Ok, I've just done some testing and I guess what I say should not happen is what actually *does* happen. Dissolve, and both Union and Merge on the Editor toolbar are planarizing the lines when run. This means a new vertex is introduced at the point of crossing, No matter what combination of options or methods I use, I can't seem to stop it from doing this. It's hard to see in OP's images (because that's showing vertex editing mode rather than selections), but the loop becomes a closed polyline with the two feeders as separate lines. Wonder if @Vince can help - if that notification even works.

Comment: would you consider C#/VB.net ArcObjects Eok? I have done this task previously for a client that didn't want to do his data cleansing manually but still wanted his pipelines clean and networked; I wrote a tool to dissolve connected lines in 1/8th of the quoted time, spent another 1/8th of the quoted time checking the results and ended up 400% productivity for that fortnight. It's a little arbitrary but as this is a one-off that shouldn't matter too much. BTW I can't/wont share compiled tools, only the source so that anybody can use it and be sure I'm not including  spyware/viruses.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson ArcObjects is an option. Coding/scripting a tool may be the next step though there is internal discussion of using the original dataset as is in the geometric network (which would annoyingly make this question moot)...

Comment: Is direction important? In my code direction is not considered important as the pipelines I was working with had sources and could easily be traced.

Comment: Direction is not important. Only interested in connectivity at the moment.

Comment: I've no idea about fully automating this approach, but if you have Standard or Advanced I'm wondering about running a topology check for pseudo-nodes (since that's what you're describing) and if when that/those tools 'fix' such a problem if they would also planarize the line. Don't really have time to test that at the moment. I know there's also a check for must not self-intersect, but that's of course what you *want* in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is VB.net code for merging lines that share a common end point, the function to call is UnsplitAllLayer0 with utility functions fFlipPC and  fJoinPC. First step is to find all the locations where two lines share an endpoint then using those locations go back through and merge both features (extend one and delete the other)... a line may be extended multiple times, this I've found is the simplest way of not loosing track of multiple dissolution operations:

```
Private Function fFlipPC(ByRef InPointColl As IPointCollection) As IPointCollection
    Dim pOutPC As IPointCollection
    Dim cnt As Long

    pOutPC = New Path
    'pOutPc.RemovePoints 0, InPointColl.PointCount - 1

    For cnt = InPointColl.PointCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        pOutPC.AddPoint(InPointColl.Point(cnt))
    Next cnt
    fFlipPC = pOutPC
End Function
Private Function fJoinPC(ByRef FirstPointColl As IPointCollection, ByRef SecondPointColl As IPointCollection) As IPointCollection
    Dim pOutPC As IPointCollection
    Dim cnt As Long

    pOutPC = FirstPointColl
    For cnt = 1 To SecondPointColl.PointCount - 1
        pOutPC.AddPoint(SecondPointColl.Point(cnt))
    Next cnt
    fJoinPC = pOutPC
End Function
Private Sub UnsplitAllLayer0()
    Dim pLayer As ILayer = My.ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.Layer(0)
    If Not (TypeOf pLayer Is IFeatureLayer) Then Exit Sub ' must be a feature layer

    Dim pFtLayer As IFeatureLayer = CType(pLayer, IFeatureLayer)
    ' step one: find the likely locations..
    Dim pLikelyLocations As IMultipoint = New MultipointClass()
    Dim pLikelyPC As IPointCollection = CType(pLikelyLocations, IPointCollection)

    ' get a cursor on all your lines
    Dim pFtCur As IFeatureCursor = pFtLayer.Search(Nothing, True)
    Dim pFeat As IFeature = pFtCur.NextFeature()

    Dim pTopOp As ITopologicalOperator
    Dim pBoundary As IGeometry
    Dim pBoundaryPC As IPointCollection
    Dim pSpatFlt As ISpatialFilter = New SpatialFilterClass()
    pSpatFlt.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects
    Dim pSrchGeom As IGeometry

    Do Until pFeat Is Nothing
        pTopOp = pFeat.ShapeCopy
        pBoundary = pTopOp.Boundary ' both ends
        pBoundaryPC = CType(pBoundary, IPointCollection)

        For pPntCnt As Integer = 0 To pBoundaryPC.PointCount - 1
            pTopOp = pBoundaryPC.Point(pPntCnt)
            pSpatFlt.Geometry = pTopOp.Buffer(0.01) ' use a suitable small number here
            If pFtLayer.FeatureClass.FeatureCount(pSpatFlt) = 2 Then
                pLikelyPC.AddPoint(pBoundaryPC.Point(pPntCnt)) ' store this point to go back later
                ' add some code here for checking attributes
                ' if that's important to your network
            End If
        Next

        pFeat = pFtCur.NextFeature() ' go next..
    Loop

    Dim pEd As IEditor = pApplication.FindExtensionByName("ESRI Object Editor") 'http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004nn000000
    pEd.StartOperation()

    ' now go through the likely locations and dissolve
    For pLikelyCnt As Integer = 0 To pLikelyPC.PointCount - 1
        pTopOp = pLikelyPC.Point(pLikelyCnt)
        pSpatFlt.Geometry = pTopOp.Buffer(0.01) ' use a suitable small number here
        Dim pUpCur As IFeatureCursor = pFtLayer.FeatureClass.Update(pSpatFlt, False) ' must be false here
        Dim pFtInto As IFeature = pUpCur.NextFeature() ' the one that will get the shape
        Dim pFtRem As IFeature = pUpCur.NextFeature()    ' the one that will be removed

        Dim pIntoPC As IPointCollection = pFtInto.ShapeCopy
        Dim pRemPC As IPointCollection = pFtRem.ShapeCopy

        ' there are 4 possibilites for line orientation:
        Dim pProxOp As IProximityOperator = pIntoPC.Point(0) ' start point
        Dim pFromFromDist = pProxOp.ReturnDistance(pRemPC.Point(0)) 'distance start-start
        Dim pFromToDist = pProxOp.ReturnDistance(pRemPC.Point(pRemPC.PointCount - 1))   ' distance start-end
        pProxOp = pIntoPC.Point(pIntoPC.PointCount - 1)
        Dim pToFromDist = pProxOp.ReturnDistance(pRemPC.Point(0))   'distance end-start
        Dim pToToDist = pProxOp.ReturnDistance(pRemPC.Point(pRemPC.PointCount - 1)) ' distance end-end

        Dim pOutPolyLine As IGeometryCollection = New PolylineClass()
        Dim pOutPath As IPointCollection = New PathClass()
        Dim pHasUpdated As Boolean = False
        If pToFromDist < 0.01 Then
            ' simplest case just extend
            pOutPath.AddPointCollection(fJoinPC(pIntoPC, pRemPC))
            pHasUpdated = True
        ElseIf pFromFromDist < 0.01 Then
            ' flip first then join
            pOutPath.AddPointCollection(fJoinPC(fFlipPC(pRemPC), pIntoPC))
            pHasUpdated = True
        ElseIf pFromToDist < 0.01 Then
            ' Extend first
            pOutPath.AddPointCollection(fJoinPC(pRemPC, pIntoPC))
            pHasUpdated = True
        ElseIf pToToDist < 0.01 Then
            ' flip second then join
            pOutPath.AddPointCollection(fJoinPC(pIntoPC, fFlipPC(pRemPC)))
            pHasUpdated = True
        End If
        If pHasUpdated Then

            pOutPolyLine.AddGeometry(pOutPath)
            Dim pOutShape As IGeometry = pOutPolyLine
            pOutShape.SpatialReference = pFtInto.ShapeCopy.SpatialReference

            ' update one and remove the other
            pFtInto.Shape = pOutShape
            pUpCur.UpdateFeature(pFtInto)
            pFtRem.Delete()
        End If
    Next

    pEd.StopOperation("Unsplit")
End Sub
```

Disclaimer: this is *very* old code, I haven't written anything in VB.net for a few years now and may or may not be the current working version... I had to dredge this one up off a backup.

Comment: Thanks for digging this out for me. Upon reviewing the code, I believe this is a viable solution. Will update when I can get it to run.

Comment: After some testing regarding editing sessions, I managed to get the bulk of the code to run almost as is in an Add-In. Many thanks Michael!

Answer (score 1):

This is my practice of removing 'parasite' nodes.

Original network with links direction shown. Links labelled by  FID:
[image]

Decide where the sink is going to be and flip relevant link if necessary. In this case I picked No 2.

[image]

Next step I call 'create network'. Script takes selected link, traces all upstream and flips them on the go if necessary. In case shown it flips only 1 link, that is No 5.

Assign node types based on combination of in/out links - another script. For simple no-diversions network "Source" node is the one where inCount=0 and outCount=1, redundant node (transition) has inCount=1 and outCount=1:

[image]

Trace all links downstream from Source (script). The list of FIDs in this case [3,0,5,1,4,2]. Build a single polyline by merging geometries in this order (script).

I don't think that scripting free approach will do here at all.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, though if I'm reading this correctly, it still requires user intervention. Also, as mentioned my comment/response, the geometric network does not have sources or sinks.

Comment: Well, make them. My original network didn't have them either. Or to be more precise it had 2 sinks, 2 sources, 1 diversion and 2 transit nodes.